# Reading body in PostRequest asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've been trying to read the body of a post request in a controller for a while but I keep getting the error that synchronous actions are not allowed. This is also meant to be used as an API so I can't just read the values trough a textbox like normal.
This is my code right now but I have no idea if this is right because this is based on Java code and my experience with asp.net core is limited.

```
public IActionResult Test()
    {
        
        string body = "";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body);
        while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            body += reader.ReadLine();
        }
        return Ok(body);
    }
```

I'm just trying to read the body so I have an idea on how I can filter on the header of the json input.
Is there maybe a different way that I can do this? Or am I forgetting something important?

Comment: If you are expecting a json content in the request body then you should use model classes instead of reading the request body manually.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I'll try to look into that thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the advice of Chetan Ranpariya, I found the answer. Like Chetan said I needed to use a model class which is pretty easy to do. I just added a folder named Models and added a class name User with this code:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And then my previous method turned into this:

```
public IActionResult Test(User user)
    {
        return Ok(new { username = user.UserName, password = user.Password });
    }
```

The only thing that I needed to pay attention to was the json body of my request. The header needs to correspond with the property name so it looked like this:

```
{
"UserName": "Admin",
"Password": "AdminPass"
}
```

And now I can continue working on my project.